# How to generate .ruc file?

Tags: microcontroller, flash, renesas

I am using RA2A1 MCU for my product and want to use **UNIQUE ID** code for security purpose and restrict the debugging without ID code.

While flashing from **Renesas Flash Programmer (RFP-3.09.01)** we required to provide security key which should be store in **.ruc file**.

My problems is that how to generate **.ruc** file.

I try to save the code in simple .txt and change the file extension from .txt to .ruc. But that method is not working and showing file is not readable (**Error00000302**).

[image: RUC file save from.txt >>.ruc]

[image: Error RUC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .ruc file needs to have specific format, not only the codes. Explanation of the format and an example is provided on Renesas documentation, see pages 36-37: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/mat/renesas-flash-programmer-v302-flash-memory-programming-software-users-manual

Have you tried using other location than OneDrive? It can sometimes cause problems.

Earlier I wrote about Notepad's default encoding, UTF-8, but it shouldn't actually matter, since UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII if you only use ASCII charset symbols in the file.

Comment: I try the steps which is shown in the user manual pg-36-37.
but when I put size of 32 It show error that "The program size exceeds the flash memory area of the target device but I put unique code in IDE it took only 32bytes of size.